# ListItem. Create managed property to sort result source

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a custom contentType "Project Info" and 'Title' property is derrived from "Item".
I want to sort via Title (I'm using rest).

I have created a result source and while using the content type the I get the desired "project-items":
ContentTypeId:0x0100A5C45A8A8F7F904EA9BDB82895CC00C6*
So far so good...

I've tried to use "Refinablestring00" and map properties similar to 'Title' managed property.
Then I try to sort the result source via "refinablestring00" and it doesnt work.
Am I missing a mapped property, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the **Mappings to Crawled Properties** setting that is forced on the OOTB RefineableStrings. The Title Managed Property is set `Include content from the first crawled property that contains information`, but the RefinableStrings all have the forced setting in SharePoint Online of `Include Content From All Crawled Properties`. Because of this, if a search result has data for more than one of the mapped crawled properties, this could affect your sort order.

Unfortunately I think this is a big short coming to SPO when it comes to Search customization that hopefully will be addressed in the future as they learn better ways to manage Search across multiple tenancies.

What I would suggest is altering the mappings to only include one crawled property (the one that corresponds with the SharePoint list item Title field) and this should give you a result that's closer to what you're looking for.